# Laravel ajax calls don't point to env APP_URL

Tags: ajax, environment-variables, laravel-5.5

I have a staging site set up at example.com/staging/public_html. Everything works as per the production site, except for the AJAX GET and POST requests, which all point to:

```
example.com/myroutehere
```

rather than

```
example.com/staging/public_html/myroutehere
```

here is the start of my AJAX request:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/estimate/{{ $id }}",
```

My APP_ENV looks like this:

```
APP_URL=http://example.com/staging/public_html/
```

(I've tried with and without the trailing slash).

Where is the AJAX request currently getting it's root path from? And how can I force it to use the APP_ENV from the .env file?

Comment: You ajax code placed in any .js page or in any .blade.php page. ?

Comment: if code placed within .blade so u can do simply

Comment: @M.Islam it's in a blade.php

Comment: it is simple. var appUrl ="{{env('APP_URL')}}"      then call url: appUrl+"/estimate/{{ $id }}"

Comment: Or better than manually cut the url together use a route, so the url is correct everywhere

Comment: If you want to point base url u can also call like this      url: "{{url('/')}}/estimate/{{ $id }}",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call from .env Simply like this .

```
var appUrl ="{{env('APP_URL')}}";
request = $.ajax({
    url: appUrl+"/estimate/{{ $id }}",
```